# tikzDevice error with knitr

Tags: r, knitr, ubuntu-16.04, tikz, tikzdevice

I'm trying to reproduce [knitr-minimal.Rnw](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rnw) with `dev='tikz'` option which produces the following error:

```
tikzDevice: R Graphics Output in LaTeX Format (v0.6.2-92-0ad2792)
  LaTeX found in the PATH using the command: pdflatex
  XeLaTeX found in the PATH using the command: xelatex
  LuaLaTeX found in the PATH using the command: lualatex
Quitting from lines 33-36 (Test1.Rnw) 
Error in tikzDevice::tikz(..., packages = c("\n\\nonstopmode\n", packages,  : 
  unused argument (verbose = FALSE)
```

My `sessionInfo()` is

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.15.20

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.0   magrittr_1.5     tools_3.4.0      tikzDevice_0.6.3 filehash_2.4-1  
 [6] stringi_1.1.5    highr_0.6        grid_3.4.0       stringr_1.2.0    evaluate_0.10
```

MWE is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1}}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\begin{document}
<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
# set global chunk options
opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figure/minimal-', fig.align='center', fig.show='hold', dev='tikz')
options(formatR.arrow=TRUE,width=90)
@

\title{A Minimal Demo of knitr}

\author{Yihui Xie}

\maketitle
You can test if \textbf{knitr} works with this minimal demo. OK, let's
get started with some boring random numbers:

<<boring-random>>=
set.seed(1121)
(x=rnorm(20))
mean(x);var(x)
@

The first element of \texttt{x} is \Sexpr{x[1]}. Boring boxplots
and histograms recorded by the PDF device:

<<boring-plots, fig.width=4, fig.height=4, out.width='.4\\linewidth'>>=
## two plots side by side (option fig.show='hold')
par(mar=c(4,4,.1,.1),cex.lab=.95,cex.axis=.9,mgp=c(2,.7,0),tcl=-.3,las=1)
boxplot(x)
hist(x,main='')
@

Do the above chunks work? You should be able to compile the \TeX{}
document and get a PDF file like this one: \url{https://github.com/yihui/knitr/releases/download/doc/knitr-minimal.pdf}.
The Rnw source of this document is at \url{https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rnw}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **tikzDevice** package seems to be too old (0.6.3). The current version is 0.10-1: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/tikzDevice/ When in doubt, `update.packages(ask = FALSE)`/